# Making it so a single line is not focusable

Tags: xaml, focus

I found a way to make an entire listBox non-focusable but I was wondering if there is a way to make a single line within the lsitbox as non-focusable?

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, if you're using MVVM:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DontFocusMeBro}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

That'll work with properties of any type, not just bool, as long as the value you want to match can be converted from the string in the `Value` attribute of the trigger. If your item property is a `bool` that's true when the item *should* be focusable, you can do it even more easily:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="{Binding MakeMeFocusable}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This assumes that your `ListBox` is populated with instances of a C# class that you wrote:

```
public class MyListItem : MyViewModelBase 
{
    private bool _dontFocusMeBro;
    public bool DontFocusMeBro {
        get { return _dontFocusMeBro; }
        set {
            if (value != _dontFocusMeBro) {
                _dontFocusMeBro = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _makeMeFocusable;
    public bool MakeMeFocusable
    {
        get { return _makeMeFocusable; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _makeMeFocusable)
            {
                _makeMeFocusable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    //  ... other properties ...
}
```

If you're populating it with strings or something, or worse yet adding `ListBoxItem` instances in a loop in your codebehind, you'll have to write a converter or something. If you give me more specifics, I can zero you in on how to make this work with your own code.